# Ordering with nested association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an app with a nested association like this:

```
user has_many timesheets
timesheet has_many invoices
```

When showing the invoice index view, I want to order the invoices on the `first_name` of the `user` it belongs to. I can do an order on the immediate parent like this:

```
Invoice.joins(:timesheet).order('timesheets.user_id')
```

Is it possible to go one level higher?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is:

```
Invoice.joins(timesheet: :user).order('users.first_name')
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answer, if the association nesting is more than one layer deep, the column name in the `order` SQL string only includes the name of the deeply nested table. For example:

```rb
Invoice.joins(timesheet: [user: :jobs]).order('jobs.completed_at')
```